# Problem with running app in android studio

Tags: java, android

So i have prbolem with running my app and it doesnt want to open, just being white background which disconnect after few seconds

````
    Process: com.example.promilek, PID: 31947
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.promilek/com.example.promilek.Login}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.promilek. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4444)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4476)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
      ```
````

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are missing a call to initialize the FirebaseApp before it resumes.

Add the following to your activity's `onCreate`:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```